# Django jQuery not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

This is what my template looks like:

```
{% extends 'typer/base.html' %}
{% load url from future %}

{% load staticfiles %}

{% block title %}{{ p_name }}{% endblock %}

{% block body_block %}
<script type='text/javascript'
src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script>
    $('#user_passage_text').on('keyup', function(e) {
        if ( e.which === 13 ) {
        var time = (new Date()).getTime() - $(this).data('time');
        $(this).data('time', 0);
        console.log('Time passed : ' + time + ' milliseconds');

        }else if ( !$(this).data('time') ){
            $(this).data('time', (new Date()).getTime());
        }
    });
</script>

    <h1>{{ p_name }}</h1>
    <p>This passage is {{ p_wlength }} words, {{ p_clength }} characters long.</p>
    {% if passage %}
        <p><blockquote>{{ p_text_body|linebreaksbr }}</blockquote></p>

    {% else %}
        The specified text {{ p_name }} does not exist!
    {% endif %}

    <p>
        Begin typing to start the test.
    </p>
    <textarea id="user_passage_text"></textarea>


{% endblock %}
```

All I want for this to do is print a message to the console to check that the function is working. The reason I'm confused about it not working is that I can run it on http://jsfiddle.net/d8c4z300/ perfectly fine. So why does the message print there but not when I run the django template?

Comment: Are there any errors messages in your browser? How does the out coming html look like?

Comment: There aren't any error messages. The out coming html looks like this: http://pastebin.com/hm1Ty7Lu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need `$(function(){ ... })` (or `$( document ).ready(function() { ... });` which is equal, only longer) around your js code:

so:

```
$(function(){

  $('#user_passage_text').on('keyup', function(e) {
    if ( e.which === 13 ) {
    var time = (new Date()).getTime() - $(this).data('time');
    $(this).data('time', 0);
    console.log('Time passed : ' + time + ' milliseconds');

    }else if ( !$(this).data('time') ){
        $(this).data('time', (new Date()).getTime());
    }
  });

});
```

fiddle is working because you set it to `onload` which is almost equal to `$(function(){ ... })` here.