# Django : Display image example jquery not working - Uncaught Reference Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I am attempting to run the following [jquery](http://jsfiddle.net/vacidesign/ja0tyj0f/) example in my django based website.I am still in the learning phase so please bear with me.

This is what portion of my code looks like so far

```
 {% extends "base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
  {% block content %}


  <input type='file' />
  <img id="myImg" src="#" alt="your ...image" />

<script>
$(function () {
    $(":file").change(function () {
        if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
        }
    });
});


function imageIsLoaded(e) {
    alert("dsdsdsd")
    $('#myImg').attr('src', e.target.result);
};
</script>



{% endblock %}
```

It seems like when I select a file the  `$(":file").change` function is not called. Any ideas why that might not be called. I tried this on jsfiddle and it  works. I am on chrome. This is what the chrome debug output shows

[image]

On hoovering over the x it states

> Uncaught Reference Error $ is not defined.

My jquery is loaded. Thats what chrome says
[image]

**Update:**

so it works like this

```
<script>
        function startup()
        {

                $(function () {
                    $(":file").change(function () {
                        if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
                            var reader = new FileReader();
                            reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
                            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
                        }
                    });
                });

                function imageIsLoaded(e) {
                    $('#myImg').attr('src', e.target.result);

                };

        }
      </script>


 <body onload="startup()">
```

I am not sure why it works like this. Any explanation would be appreciated.
Why does it need to be inside the `startup`

Comment: `$("input[type='file']").change` ??

Comment: That means your `jQuery` most likely isn't loaded when the script is being read/executed. Make sure your `jQuery` library is read in first.

Comment: I placed the it inside the `<script>` tag and that is at the end

Comment: jQuery should be before your script... not at the end.

Comment: Put your `<script src='jQuery.js'>...` in the `<head>` tags

Comment: I tried it at the beginning too but it still does not work. I wonder if it might have something to do with django

Comment: Adjit is right, put the script reference to jquery at the top. make sure your jquery code that you wrote is in a script tag below it. Also if you are in chrome, open up the debugger and go to the network tab. Refresh the page and verify you are getting the jquery script successfully. if you get a 404 you aren't referenceing it at the right path

Comment: You may be right about `django` I think that may also use the `$` alias. Try `jQuery` instead of `$`

Comment: @MorningDew will give this a try

Comment: @Adjit i think this a django thing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27730080/django-jquery-not-working

Comment: @MorningDew unfortunately that does not work

Comment: @JamesFranco did you get a 200 response on the jquery request?

Comment: @MorningDew I got a 304

Comment: @all just updated my post

Comment: 304 : «If a 304 response indicates an entity not currently cached, then the cache MUST disregard the response and repeat the request without the conditional.» [reference here](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

Comment: @JamesFranco did that question solve you issue?

Comment: @Adjit nope. I just updated my post with how I solved it. I am not sure why that works.

Comment: Post that as the answer in that case. But the reason why that works is because the function isn't being executed until the `body` is loaded. Therefore, it is not throwing an error, because you are not trying to execute something by using `$` until the `body` / scripts including jQuery is done loading

Comment: @Adjit Thanks for clearing that up

Comment: Also, while that does work, I would still consider looking further into trying to solve the issue without a workaround.

Comment: I am not sure why that is an issue. I am still confused as the jquery function was inside a script tag. Even if you specify stuff inside the script tag and thats inside the body nothing should happen.Why was i getting an invalid reference error

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the problem

```
<script>
        function startup()
        {

                $(function () {
                    $(":file").change(function () {
                        if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
                            var reader = new FileReader();
                            reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
                            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
                        }
                    });
                });

                function imageIsLoaded(e) {
                    $('#myImg').attr('src', e.target.result);

                };

        }
      </script>


 <body onload="startup()">
```